# Getting infinite loop using cycle-idb with text field for input

Tags: javascript, cyclejs

I've been trying to create a simple test app that takes user input from a text field, displays it, and also persists it with [cycle-idb](https://github.com/cyclejs-community/cycle-idb). But I keep falling into infinite loops, no matter what I do.

Here's the whole main function:

```
function intent(domSources) {
  return domSources.select('.name')
    .events('input')
    .map(ev => ev.target.value);
};

function model(input$, db$) {
  const log$ = db$;
  return xs.combine(input$, log$)
    .map(([input, logs]) => {
      return {
        id: 1,
        name: input,
      }
    }).startWith({id: 1, name: ""});
};

function view(state$) {
  return state$.map(log => {
    return (
      <div>
        <label for='name'>Name: </label>
        <input 
          className='name' 
          type='text' 
          value={log.name}
          placeholder="Enter a log name"
        />
        <p>{log.name}</p>
      </div>
    )
  });
};

function persist(state$) {
  return state$.map(log => {
    return $put('logs', log)
  });
};

export function main (sources) {
  const db$ = sources.IDB.store('logs').getAll();
  const input$ = intent(sources.DOM);
  const state$ = model(input$, db$);
  const vtree$ = view(state$);
  const updateDb$ = persist(state$);

  return {
    DOM: vtree$,
    IDB: updateDb$,
  };
}
```

I'm trying use the MVI and using TodoMVC as an example but I can't figure out how to manage the circular dependencies without creating that infinite loop.

Any advice or pointers to other references would be much appreciated.

Comment: It shouldnt make a difference, but can you try instead of `take(1)` and `combine` to use `sampleCombine`?

Comment: thanks @JanvanBrügge, yea, may not, though I feel like my issue does concern being able to take an update from the db once, and from then on, only update the db, and not the other way around.

Comment: edited this to remove `take(1)`... wrong version of the code, which stops the infinite loop, but breaks the db updates

Answer (score 0):

The hack to this is to use dropRepeats doing deep comparison.

The answer from gitter that points to "optimized" solution:

```
function model(input$, db$) {
  return xs.merge(xs.never(), db$.take(1)).map(name => {
    return input$.startWith(name).map(name => {
      return { id: 1, name }
    })
  }).flatten()
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this produces more errors in the database. First, it initializes the name property as an empty array, but then doesn't update the db after that. Seems like the `take(1)` is still terminating the stream to the database sink, though that still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: the best working version I've come to yet is this: https://github.com/jgaehring/farmos-cycle/blob/master/src/app.jsx . I'm using dropRepeats in the persist function, at your recommendation. Do you want to use this to edit your answer so I can accept it? You're def due the credit! :)

Comment: added infinite stream to take(), hopefully it won't terminate as there's a special symbol for that to happen.

Comment: still the same problem. :/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52482585/1549703) results in breaking the stream of updates to the database.

In gitter, @janat08 suggested the following changes to the `persist` function, which *did* work for me:

```
function persist(state$) {
  return state$.compose(dropRepeats((x, y) => {
    return x.id === y.id && x.name === y.name;
  })).map(log => {
    return $put('logs', log)
  });
};
```

Not marking this as the solution yet, so Jan has a chance to edit his solution, or if someone comes up wiht a less hacky solution.